# Android XML: Drop shadow cut off

Tags: android, xml, dropshadow

I have a relative layout with a margin and a floating action button that is nested inside this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activityMargin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clipToPadding="false">


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/id_FABSave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_save_white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see in the attached picture, the drop shadow of the floating action button is cut off. How does this happen and how can it be fixed?

[image: Bottom and right side of shadow cut off]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In your relative layout tag, use padding instead of margin and add the attribute `android:clipToPadding="false"` to avoid the shadows being cut.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/activityMargin"
        android:clipToPadding="false">
```

Comment: I tried that, sadly it does not work. I'll edit my post.

Comment: oh, because of layout_margin! I've updated my answer

Answer (score 5):

Problem is that shadows are cut by bounds of view or view group. To tackle this issue you have to use:

```
android:clipChildren
```

> Defines whether a child is limited to draw inside of its bounds or not.

```
android:clipToPadding
```

> Defines whether the ViewGroup will clip its children and resize (but not clip) any EdgeEffect to its padding, if padding is not zero.

Problem is that you have to set this to many views in xml if you want to render shadow. I resolved this issue on level of themes.xml. In my top level theme I just set:

```
<item name="android:clipChildren">false</item>
<item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
```

Then, if there is space on screen, shadow is rendered. I hope it won't break something else.

**EDIT:** It breaks some views. For example CameraPreview will set black background to whole screen. Be careful with scrolling views, etc.

Comment: This should be correct answer, clipToPadding is not always enough. Both clipChildren and clipToPadding worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, but be careful with those properties. They can really break visual of things.